# Where to get fresh rose petals( rosa demascena) that are organic and/or pesticide free

Tags: flowers

I need to make rose water and therefore need fresh rose petals (rosa demascena) that are organic and/or pesticide free. Is there any place to get these in the uk?

Comment: You probably can't. Damascena is seldom grown in Western Europe, except for some plantations in Southern France. And even there, it's sold to industrial buyers, the demand among home cooks is so low that there simply isn't a market.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of trouble when high-quality rose water can pretty easily be found in high-end grocers, professional bakery suppliers, or online.

Answer (score 3):

I bet a whole foods or organic market would be a good first place to look.

Alternatively, Ask anyone who grows them. From what I understand roses are very popular in the UK. I bet there is someone who doesn't spray and feed their roses with chemicals.

Comment: +1, getting roses and picking the petals off is probably the simplest source.

Comment: Sure, if you can find someone who grows damascena, it's probably a good way to get them. But most people grow decorative roses, which are tasteless.

Comment: You can also try middle eastern and sometimes Asian markets also